# Jenkins pipeline to create Maven artifacts and a Docker image

Tags: maven, jenkins-pipeline

I need my pipeline to produce a SNAPSHOT or release artifact, and then also produce a Docker image tagged with latest, or with the version number of the release. I am using the fabric8 plugin and taking advantage of the feature that will produce a tag based on the version field of the POM file.

Due to the order of the stages the tag will always be latest, regardless of whether its a snapshot or a release. I need some help to determine the proper way to do this as I cant see a way to put them in a different order.

The tools involved are Maven + fabric8, Jenkins, Artifactory, and SVN.

After the Maven release and prepare steps the POM will have a SNAPSHOT version, so the stage "Create Docker Image" will always produce a tag of 'latest'.

I could do something like figure out what the SVN tag url is for the released version and check it out and then do my build. That feels wrong though, but maybe not. There has to be a more "official" way of doing this.

```
pipeline{
    agent any
    
    tools{
        maven 'M3'
    }
    
    parameters {
        booleanParam(
            name: 'RELEASE',
            description: 'Build a release from current commit.',
            defaultValue: false
        )
        booleanParam(
            name: 'SCAN_CODE',
            description: 'Scan your code to see how awesome it is.',
            defaultValue: true
        )        
    }
    
    environment {
        ARTIFACT_ID = readMavenPom().getArtifactId()
    }
    
    stages{
        stage("Unit tests"){
            steps{
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS test '
                }
            }
        }
        stage("SonarQube Scan"){
            when {
                expression { params.SCAN_CODE == true}
            }         
            steps{
                withSonarQubeEnv('codequality') {
                    configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                        sh 'mvn clean install -gs $MVN_SETTINGS ' + 
                                'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar -f pom.xml ' +
                                '-DskipTests' +
                                '-Dsonar.projectKey=com.etisoftware:$ARTIFACT_ID ' +
                                '-Dsonar.login=$DOCKER_REPO_USER ' +
                                '-Dsonar.password=$DOCKER_REPO_PASSWORD ' +
                                '-Dsonar.language=java ' +
                                '-Dsonar.sources=. ' +
                                '-Dsonar.tests=. ' +
                                '-Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/** ' +
                                '-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*Test*/**'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Quality Gate") {
            when {
                expression { params.SCAN_CODE == true}
            }          
            steps {
                timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                    // Parameter indicates whether to set pipeline to UNSTABLE if Quality Gate fails
                    // true = set pipeline to UNSTABLE, false = don't
                    waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
                }
            }
        }        
        stage("Build Snapshot"){
            when {
                expression { params.RELEASE == false}
            } 
            steps{
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS -DskipTests clean deploy'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Release") {
            when {
                expression { params.RELEASE == true}
            }
            steps {
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS clean; ' + 
                       'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS -B release:prepare; ' +
                       'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS -B release:perform'
                }
            }
        }
        stage("Create Docker Image"){
            steps{
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS ' +
                        '-Ddocker.username=${DOCKER_REPO_USER} -Ddocker.password=${DOCKER_REPO_PASSWORD} ' +
                        '-DskipTests ' +
                        'clean package spring-boot:repackage ' +
                        'docker:build docker:push'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    
    post{
        always{
            cleanWs()
        }

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to use the POM file from target/checkout. See the stage labeled "Create Docker Image For Release".

```
pipeline{
agent any

tools{
    maven 'M3'
}

parameters {
    booleanParam(
        name: 'RELEASE',
        description: 'Build a release from current commit.',
        defaultValue: false
    )
    booleanParam(
        name: 'SCAN_CODE', 
        description: 'Scan your code to see how awesome it is.',
        defaultValue: true
    )        
}

environment {
    ARTIFACT_ID = readMavenPom().getArtifactId()
}

stages{
    stage("Unit tests"){
        steps{
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS test '
            }
        }
    }
    stage("SonarQube Scan"){
        when {
            expression { params.SCAN_CODE == true}
        }         
        steps{
            withSonarQubeEnv('codequality') {
                configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                    sh 'mvn clean install -gs $MVN_SETTINGS ' + 
                            'org.sonarsource.scanner.maven:sonar-maven-plugin:3.3.0.603:sonar -f pom.xml ' +
                            '-DskipTests' +
                            '-Dsonar.projectKey=com.etisoftware:$ARTIFACT_ID ' +
                            '-Dsonar.login=$DOCKER_REPO_USER ' +
                            '-Dsonar.password=$DOCKER_REPO_PASSWORD ' +
                            '-Dsonar.language=java ' +
                            '-Dsonar.sources=. ' +
                            '-Dsonar.tests=. ' +
                            '-Dsonar.test.inclusions=**/*Test*/** ' +
                            '-Dsonar.exclusions=**/*Test*/**'
                }
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Quality Gate") {
        when {
            expression { params.SCAN_CODE == true}
        }          
        steps {
            timeout(time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                // Parameter indicates whether to set pipeline to UNSTABLE if Quality Gate fails
                // true = set pipeline to UNSTABLE, false = don't
                waitForQualityGate abortPipeline: true
            }
        }
    }        
    stage("Build Snapshot"){
        when {
            expression { params.RELEASE == false}
        } 
        steps{
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS -DskipTests clean deploy'
            }
        }
    }
    // SNAPSHOTS
    stage("Create Docker Image For SNAPSHOT"){
        when {
            expression { params.RELEASE == false}
        }        
        steps{
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS ' +
                    '-Ddocker.username=${DOCKER_REPO_USER} -Ddocker.password=${DOCKER_REPO_PASSWORD} ' +
                    '-DskipTests ' +
                    'clean package spring-boot:repackage ' +
                    'docker:build docker:push'
            }
        }
    }        
    // RELEASES
    stage("Release") {
        when {
            expression { params.RELEASE == true}
        }
        steps {
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS clean'
                sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS -B release:prepare'
                sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS -B release:perform'
            }
        }
    }
    stage("Create Docker Image For Release"){
        when {
            expression { params.RELEASE == true}
        }        
        steps{
            configFileProvider([configFile(fileId: '1a4e39cc-eacf-4bd0-af47-337f536fd2bd', variable: 'MVN_SETTINGS')]) {
                sh 'mvn -gs $MVN_SETTINGS ' +
                    '-f target/checkout/pom.xml ' +
                    '-Ddocker.username=${DOCKER_REPO_USER} -Ddocker.password=${DOCKER_REPO_PASSWORD} ' +
                    '-DskipTests ' +
                    'clean package spring-boot:repackage ' +
                    'docker:build docker:push'
            }
        }
    }
}

post{
    always{
        cleanWs()
    }
}
```

}

Comment: I am trying to define a similar jenkins pipeline but I get an error "[INFO] I/O exception (java.io.IOException) caught when processing request to {}->docker://localhost:2376: com.sun.jna.LastErrorException: [2] No such file or directory" probably because the docker container spawned by jenkins to execute the pipeline doesn't have docker itself. Any suggestions or troubleshooting tips?